# Python Cannot Find File Specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to rename a file, but python cannot find the file specified.

I have a file located here:

```
C:\Users\my_username\Desktop\selenium_downloads\close_of_day_reports\close-of-day-2022-04-24-2022-04-23.pdf
```

I am trying to rename the file to `test.pdf`

Here is the code I am using:

```
import os

os.rename(
     src = "C:\\Users\\my_username\\Desktop\\selenium_downloads\\close_of_day_reports\\close-of-day-2022-04-24-2022-04-23.pdf",
     dst = "C:\\Users\\my_username\\Desktop\\selenium_downloads\\close_of_day_reports\\test.pdf"

)
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\my_username\\Desktop\\selenium_downloads\\close_of_day_reports\\close-of-day-2022-04-24-2022-04-23.pdf' -> 

'C:\\Users\\my_username\\Desktop\\selenium_downloads\\close_of_day_reports\\test.pdf'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1:**

- The original file was not deleted, it still exists.
- It's really strange, when I run it the first time, the file does not get renamed, but when I run it again, it does.
- Weird, for some reason it works in Python Shell, but not my Python file.

**Edit #2:**

I am using Selenium to download the file. When I comment the part of my code out that downloads the file from Selenium, my os.rename code works fine. Weird.

Comment: You are still specifying the non test.pdf

Comment: ```python
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\my_usernamer\\Desktop\\selenium_downloads\\close_of_day_reports\\close-of-day-2022-04-24-2022-04-23.pdf' ->```

Comment: FYI there are "raw strings" in Python, where you just add "r" before the first quote in the string, so that you can enter in paths without having to add any escape characters. So it could just look like `r"C:\Users\whatever\blah\file.pdf"` More info here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: Question - was the file already renamed? Maybe the original doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: The original file exists

Comment: @ChickenSandwichNoPickles Can you manually rename it?

Comment: figured it out, see my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you ran the code once, renamed the file, and now it won't run again because you already renamed it.

Comment: No, that did not happen. Confirmed.

Comment: Also, I manually went in and deleted ALL files before rerunning each time for test purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Careful reading is your friend. Computers don't know or care what you meant:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Users\my_username**r**\Desktop\selenium_downloads\close_of_day_reports\close-of-day-2022-04-24-2022-04-23.pdf'

See the stray **r** in the path?

Comment: I copied the error messages and took out my username for security reasons. I corrected my original post, thank you. Good catch.

Comment: Wouldn’t you agree this is *very* likely a typo.  What are the chances the username is actually  'my_username'?

Comment: Yes, when I copied my code and replaced my actual username with "my_username" for security purposes,  it was indeed a typo.

Comment: Fair enough. So you've verified that the path in the error message is _exactly_ correct? E.g. by using it from a Windows prompt to open the file that Python cannot find?

Answer (score 0):

Based off the error, I think you are still leaving one the original name or not changing the right one.

```py
import os

os.rename(
     src = "C:\\Users\\my_username\\Desktop\\selenium_downloads\\close_of_day_reports\\test.pdf",
     dst = "C:\\Users\\my_username\\Desktop\\selenium_downloads\\close_of_day_reports\\close-of-day-2022-04-24-2022-04-23.pdf"

)
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm

src = the original file
dst = the name of the new file

So my order was correct, at least, from what I understand. Am I wrong?

Comment: Just for laughs and giggles, I did try switching it though and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

When you download files using Selenium, you need to put in a sleep method for a few seconds and then you can download/move files without a problem.

Put this in your code after downloading the file, before downloading another:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(10)
pass
```

You may need to increase the sleep value, but 10 worked for me. The number inside of sleep represents seconds, so sleep(10) means to wait 10 seconds.

Comment: Glad you found it!